# Add Drag&Drop with Behaviors

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, desktop-application, attachedbehaviors

I need to modify a desktop application which uses WPF, MVVM and Behaviors for event handling. I've got a task to implement Drag&Drop for a button. If the user presses the button it will popup a file-save window but if the user clicks and drags it, it should display a file icon and the let the user drop it into an Explorer window to save it there.

I've already added namespaces:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Desktop.Client.Behaviors"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
```

I've also added XAML code into the button:

```
<Button Grid.Column="2"
  Command="{Binding SaveAttachmentCommand}"
  Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" 
  Style="{StaticResource AttachmentSaveButtonStyle}">

  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
    <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LeftMouseButtonDownCommand}"/>
  </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>

  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:FrameworkElementDragBehavior>
    </behaviors:FrameworkElementDragBehavior>
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

But I don't know how to tell the behavior class (FrameworkElementDragBehavior) which events to handle and how to handle them (what functions to call).

I've read some tutorials but I'm still confused.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do Drag and drop with MVVM two months ago.

After some research, personnaly, the best way to achieve that is to work with the "GongSolutions DragDrop" library.
It's very simple and it's perfect for what you're looking for.
For example, in a treeview:

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding LstCat}" 
              dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" 
              dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
              dd:DragDrop.DragAdornerTemplate="{StaticResource DragAdorner}">
    //Treeview Structure

    </TreeView>
```

From there you can do Drag&Drop in the treeview. You can add a dragAdorner too (an image next to your pointer when you are dragging something)

In the viewModel you can tell the behaviour of the dragging or Dropping by implementing an interface which comes with the library. This way you can access to the data your dragging.
For example:

```
    public void DragOver(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        if (dropInfo.Data is Category && dropInfo.TargetItem is Rubrique)
        {
            return;
        }

        dropInfo.DropTargetAdorner = DropTargetAdorners.Highlight;
        dropInfo.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
```

Here is the link of the library if you're interested: 
https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop